# Set diagonal of a matrix to zero in R

Tags: r

I have tried a few proposed solution in here. But it was not working for my case.
I have a code, here:

```
a <- read.table("Whirr_127.csv", header=T, sep=",", row.names=1) # task assignment / people vs task
b <- read.table("Files_Whirr_127.csv", header=T, sep=",", row.names=1) #task vs files 
a
b

#calc cr , cr = ta * tf * transpose(ta)
cr <- as.matrix(a) %*% (as.matrix(b) %*% as.matrix(t(b)) %*% as.matrix(t(a)))
cr

#set value to 1, to initialize table
cr[cr>=1]<-1
cr

#identify diagonal matrix, set to zero
cr<-as.matrix(0,ncol=ncol(cr),nrow=nrow(cr))
cr<-diag(cr,x=0)
```

I want to set diagonal value as zero. It seems the code used in the last two lines are not working for my case.

Also, I would like to used the file name in `a`, and saved it as AB_Files_Whirr_127.csv
I tried to use

```
write.csv(cr,file = paste("CR_", a,".csv")
```

but, nothing appear in my directory.

sample output for cr:

```
               Adrian Cole Alison Wong Andrei Savu Bruno Dumon Edward J. Yoon Eugene Koontz Jakob Homan Kelvin Kakugawa Kirk True Lars George Soren Macbeth Stu Hood
Adrian Cole               0           0           0           0              0             0           0               0         0           0             0        0
Alison Wong               0           0           0           0              0             0           0               0         0           0             0        0
Andrei Savu               0           0           1           0              0             0           0               0         0           1             1        0
Bruno Dumon               0           0           0           0              0             0           0               0         0           0             0        0
Edward J. Yoon            0           0           0           0              0             0           0               0         0           0             0        0
Eugene Koontz             0           0           0           0              0             0           0               0         0           0             0        0
Jakob Homan               0           0           0           0              0             0           0               0         0           0             0        0
Kelvin Kakugawa           0           0           0           0              0             0           0               0         0           0             0        0
Kirk True                 0           0           0           0              0             0           0               0         0           0             0        0
Lars George               0           0           1           0              0             0           0               0         0           1             1        0
Soren Macbeth             0           0           1           0              0             0           0               0         0           1             1        0
Stu Hood                  0           0           0           0              0             0           0               0         0           0             0        0
Tibor Kiss                0           0           0           0              0             0           0               0         0           0             0        0
Tom White                 0           0           1           0              0             0           0               0         0           1             1        0
Unassigned                0           0           0           0              0             0           0               0         0           0             0        0
                Tibor Kiss Tom White Unassigned
Adrian Cole              0         0          0
Alison Wong              0         0          0
Andrei Savu              0         1          0
Bruno Dumon              0         0          0
Edward J. Yoon           0         0          0
Eugene Koontz            0         0          0
Jakob Homan              0         0          0
Kelvin Kakugawa          0         0          0
Kirk True                0         0          0
Lars George              0         1          0
Soren Macbeth            0         1          0
Stu Hood                 0         0          0
Tibor Kiss               0         0          0
Tom White                0         1          0
Unassigned               0         0          0
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`a` cannot be used in the name of the output file as it is not a character variable, it is a data frame.

```
infile <- "Whirr_127.csv"
a <- read.table(infile, header=T, sep=",", row.names=1)
....
diag(cr) <- 0
write.csv(cr, file = paste0("CR_", infile, ".csv")
```

The syntax of the `diag` line tends to look funny to new R users, but it is actually just an alternate syntax to call the assignment function `diag<-`, i.e. `diag(x) <- 0` is interpreted as `diag<-(x, 0)`.

**Update: Multiple files**

If you want to repeat the above for multiple paired files you can do this.

```
a.files <- grep("^Whirr", dir(), value=TRUE)
b.files <- paste0("Files_", a.files)
for(i in length(a.files)){
    a <- read.table(a.files[i], ...)
    b <- read.table(b.files[i], ...)
    ...
    write.csv(cr, paste0("CR_", a.files[i], ".csv"))
}
```

Comment: thank you, the diagonal solution work for me, but the file is not appear in my working directory...

Comment: I edited the post at the same time you read it probably. The solution with `paste0("CR_", infile, ".csv")` should definatelly work. If not make sure that the `paste0` command returns a character scalar.

Comment: it is just a simple solution for diag. silly me! anyway, let say, I have multiple file, thats mean I have to replace infile (file = paste0("CR_", infile, ".csv") with filepath? IS it correct?

Comment: Do a loop and set infile to different files in each iteration. I suspect the files come in pairs of `"Whirr_###.csv"` and matching `"Files_Whirr_###.csv"` though, is that right?

Comment: I tried to run the script my using multiple files. But, I got this error:Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'Files_ Whirr_128.csv': No such file or directory

Comment: it works now. I have to use paste instead of paste0. Thank you for your help.